# RabbitMQ order of acks when using multiple consumers

Tags: queue, rabbitmq

I am plannning to use RabbitMQ with java and like to know rabbitMQ behavior with order of Ack.

Here is my scenario.

Consider 3 messages x,y,z picked by the 3 differnt consumer in the same order. y and z gets succesfull ack first at this point is it possible to send negative ack to message x ?. What I gather from my reading on their documenataion is that it is not possible -  Is this something not possible with rabbitMQ ?

With multiple consumers I assume this is a common scenario. Are there other queueing products that support this ?.

Comment: Yes you can, where did you read that it is not possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each rabbit consumer is working it's own "bucket" of work and it does not have knowledge of what the other consumers are working on.  So in that sense, no, you can't do what you're describing with what is built into Rabbit.

You could of course write your own code that ties N consumers together (something like SignalR) so you let all the other consumers know that you're finished with x.

Comment: thanks for your reply.  I will take a look at Singal R